# Elasticsearch Group by a field and get the count of buckets which are having more than 2 documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Trying to find a way to get the count of buckets in terms of aggregation where each bucket is having at least two documents in it.

Was able to get the buckets, and keeping the size large enough to get all the buckets, but I really want to know how to get the total bucket count:

```
"aggregations": {
    "by_universalId": {
        "terms": {
          "size": 10, 
            "field": "universalId",
            "min_doc_count": 2,
            "order": [
                {
                    "_count": "desc"
                },
                {
                    "_key": "asc"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/54649#fromHistory) GitHub thread says, bucket selector is the right way to get the count, but couldn't figure out a way to do it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT1:
This is how the index data looks like:

```
{"id":"1", "universalId": "a"}
{"id":"2", "universalId": "a"}
{"id":"3", "universalId": "b"}
{"id":"4", "universalId": "b"}
{"id":"5", "universalId": "c"}
{"id":"6", "universalId": "c"}
{"id":"7", "universalId": "d"}
{"id":"8", "universalId": "d"}
{"id":"9", "universalId": "e"}
{"id":"10", "universalId": "e"}
{"id":"11", "universalId": "f"}
{"id":"12", "universalId": "f"}
{"id":"13", "universalId": "f"}
{"id":"14", "universalId": "g"}
{"id":"15", "universalId": "g"}
{"id":"16", "universalId": "g"}
{"id":"17", "universalId": "g"}
{"id":"18", "universalId": "h"}
{"id":"19", "universalId": "i"}
{"id":"20", "universalId": "j"}
```

And when I run this query I get the count as 5, instead of 7:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
      "by_universalId": {
        "terms": {
          "size": 5,
          "field": "universalId",
          "min_doc_count": 2,
          "order": [
            {
              "_count": "desc"
            },
            {
              "_key": "asc"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "bucketcount": {
        "stats_bucket": {
          "buckets_path": "by_universalId._count"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "by_universalId" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 4,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "g",
          "doc_count" : 4
        },
        {
          "key" : "f",
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : "a",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "b",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "c",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    },
    "bucketcount" : {
      "count" : 5,
      "min" : 2.0,
      "max" : 4.0,
      "avg" : 2.6,
      "sum" : 13.0
    }
  }
```

If I change the size to 10, then I get the correct count, which is 7.

**I am expecting the count to be 7, regardless of the size I pass in terms of aggregation.**

Elasticsearch version details:

```
"version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
```

Comment: can you please explain your use case with the help of an example. It would be great if you can share some sample index data and expected search result

Comment: I was trying to find the duplicates for an entity. Two documents will be considered as duplicates if they have the same universalId. Now i need pull up the count of entities which have at least one duplicate.

Similar to what google shows for duplicate contacts in android phones.

I'll try to create the sample index data and expected results and will update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the total count of buckets formed by terms aggregation (having min doc count as 2), then you need to use [stats bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-stats-bucket-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "by_universalId": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 10,
        "field": "universalId",
        "min_doc_count": 2,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "bucketcount": {
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "by_universalId._count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

**You are getting the count of buckets using stats_bucket aggregation (using the above search query). By default `size` parameter in the terms aggregation defaults to 10.**

The [size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) parameter is used to set the number of buckets that should be returned in the aggregation result. If you're specifying `"size :5"`, then only 5 buckets will be returned, and on the basis of that stats bucket aggregation will return count as 5.

***In your case, if you don't even pass the `size` parameter in the terms aggregation, you will get the count as 7***

Comment: Does the stats_bucket depends on the `size` in the terms aggregation(`by_universalId`)? Because `bucketcount` is same as `size` if `size` is provided, otherwise it will fallback to the default page size(in my case it was 10)

Comment: @Madhu `stats_bucket` will give you the count of the number of buckets that are formed by the terms aggregation.

Comment: @Madhu now you are getting the count of terms buckets using stats bucket aggregation. I have updated the answer regarding the issue related to the `size` parameter. Please go through the updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: yeah not passing `size` works in this case, but if the number of buckets is large(say 10,000), then just to count the buckets i'll be fetching all of the buckets. Is there any other way i can do this, without fetching all the buckets or limiting the number of buckets i fetch at any time to a small number, but still get the total bucket count that matches the criteria?

Comment: @Madhu As far as I know there is no other way to find duplicates(having min doc count 2) apart from using bucket aggregation (here terms aggregation). And for that, you have to fetch all the buckets and set the `size` parameter accordingly if you have 10k docs